# Rails server not running after new rvm install and bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Ok i just run my bundle install and when i try to run my rails server with "rails s" i get the following error messages:

```
rails s
/home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `mkdir': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.gem.20140807-24550-jnrbg

Gem files will remain installed in /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/bcrypt-3.1.7/gem_make.out
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `block in mktmpdir'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:142:in `create'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:85:in `mktmpdir'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:14:in `build'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:9:in `<main>'
```

I've also tried running gem install rails separatley in hopes of resolving the issue but that did not work.

OS: ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32 bit)

Any pointers on how i can fix this?

Thanks people!

Comment: install as `sudo` user

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that please?

Comment: oh I may be wrong, you had no problems while bundle insatll?

Comment: no problems at all. just some Post-install messages from some of the gems. but no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Weird: you get an install error when running `rails s`? You could try to run the command in the context of the already installed bundle, by doing

```
bundle exec rails s
```

but not sure if it will help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this this happens after an exception (missing system software), during a previous bundle install, which did not generate the error.

So you fix the system software, install the trouble-gem ok, then this happens when you run 'bundle install' again after that.  You can change permissions all day, and it will keep creating new filenames it says it cannot write to.

First thing to try - open a new shell, cd to the same directory, and try again.  That fixed it for me.